# Truth Table in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I  have to program the behavior of an entity:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity truth_table is
    port(   A,B,C,D : in    std_logic;
            O       : out   std_logic);
end truth_table;
```

This entity is declared in the file with this code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

architecture behavior of truth_table is

begin

end behavior;
```

and has the following properties:

• Inputs: A, B, C, D with type std logic

• Outputs: O with type std logic

The first (code) entity shall behave according to the following truth table:

[image]

Prior simplification with an optimization algorithm like Karnaugh Veith (KV diagram) is encouraged.

What I have done?

[image]

Am I going in right direction?

Comment: Have you done your optimization yet?

Comment: It always says Process "Synthesize - XST" failed @A.Kieffer

Comment: No. Read the last line of the problem statement. Take the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to post your code as `code` instead of an image. Even as an image, I can see that you have got:

```
0 <= A AND B AND C AND D; -- your output is O, not 0
```

You have repeated the same assignment twice for some reason.

The boolean equation does not match the truth table.

Comment: Can you help how should I form boolean equation

Comment: @Azra There are many videos on youtube with explanations and worked examples of 4-variable Karnaugh maps that do a much better job at helping you understand how to use them than I could do in a few paragraphs here.

Comment: @Azra sorry I don't understand what you mean by 'the first block'. Just draw your 4x4 grid K-map and extract the equation. There is no 'first block'.

Comment: @Azra the truth table has 4 blocks, but this is just how somebody has decided to draw the table. All the information in that one *truth table* needs to be transposed into *one K-map*

Comment: I get that output O=NOT A and C + B and C and D @scary_jeff

Comment: Acutally I get y=NotAC +BCD

Comment: The right equation is rather O = (not D and B) or (A and B and C)